# How to display a SQL Server database record once that has a many to many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm using ASP.NET C# to output the results from a SQL Server database query and trying to get the results to display only one record per court but that also displays multiple contact details per court.

The tables concerned are (PK in bold, FK in Italics):

Court (**Court_ID**, Court_Name, Note, Town, Postcode)

Contacts (**Contact_ID**, Contacts_Name, Contacts_no, *Court_ID*, *Court_Contact_Type_ID*)

Contact_Type (**Court_Contact_Type_ID**, Court_Contact_Type_Desc)

Currently my issue is that I get multiple repetitions of each court detail for as many contacts as each court has. I know why it's doing it, but I don't know the method for how to make it work the way I want.

I'm not sure if the solution lies within the SQL query itself (maybe resolved by nesting...?) or with the C# code because I'm using 'HasRows'. I've included both code snippets below.

```
string myQuery = "SELECT Court_Name, Town, Postcode, Note, Contacts_Name, Contacts_no, Court_Contact_Type_Desc " +
                 "FROM Court C, Contacts CON, Contact_type CONT " +
                 "WHERE C.Court_ID = CON.Court_ID AND CON.Court_Contact_Type_ID = CONT.Court_Contact_Type_ID AND C.Court_ID = '3' ";


SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStr);
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(myQuery, connection);
SqlDataReader myDataReader;
connection.Open();

myDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

if (myDataReader.HasRows)
{

    while (myDataReader.Read())
    {

        string court_name = myDataReader["Court_Name"].ToString();
        string court_town = myDataReader["Town"].ToString();
        string court_pcode = myDataReader["Postcode"].ToString();
        string court_note = myDataReader["Note"].ToString();
        string court_contact_name = myDataReader["Contacts_Name"].ToString();
        string court_contact_desc = myDataReader["Court_Contact_Type_Desc"].ToString();
        string court_contacts_no = myDataReader["Contacts_no"].ToString();

        Response.Write("<strong>" + court_name + "</strong><br>" + court_town + "<br>" + court_pcode + "<p>" + court_note + "</p>" + "<p>" + court_contact_name + " - " + court_contact_desc + " : " + court_contacts_no + "</p>");

    }

}
```

The eventual output should look something like this:

**Abergavenny Magistrates' Court**
Abergavenny
NP7 5DL

This court is open for hearings only. Additional Court Notes….

**Contacts**
Contact Name 1 - Acting Court Manager: 01633 64xxxx
Contact Name 2 - Acting Office Manager: 01633 64xxxx
Contact Name 3 - Acting List Officer: 01633 64xxxx
Contact Name 4 - Justices' Clerk: 01633 64xxxx

As ever any help gratefully received!

Cheers

Comment: Use DISTINCT or GROUP BY

Comment: @Dev I don't think DISTINCT would work because each row is unique (Combination of Court, Contact and Contact Type). Dan Solo, Can you show an example of how you want it to be displayed?

Comment: If a court has multiple contact details how do you want to aggregate them, first? Last? Some harmonisation? Only the contacts for the head clerk? Do you want courts that have no contacts?

Comment: You probably want to use join conditions too.

Comment: Each court has many contacts, if you want only one row per court, then which contact you want have in that row?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**20 years** ago!). ***Please*** stop using it

Comment: How can you display multiple courts when your query asks for court_id of `'3'`? I assume it's only an example, right?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, Not ` multiple courts` but `multiple repetitions of each court`.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I understand that multiple repetitions is what the OP is trying to eliminate; however, "display only one record per court" from the question implies to me that there would be multiple courts.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight `per court` is applicable to one court too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the problem like this:

- Add court_id to the select list
- Add ordering criteria that put rows that belong to the same court next to each other
- When iterating through the data coming back, see if you have seen the court id before
- If this is the first time that you see the court id, show both the court and the contact details
- If you have seen this court id before, show only the contact information

Here is an example of how you can do it:

```
string myQuery = "SELECT C.Court_ID, Court_Name, Town, Postcode, Note, Contacts_Name, Contacts_no, Court_Contact_Type_Desc " +
             "FROM Court C "+
             "JOIN Contacts CON ON C.Court_ID = CON.Court_ID "+
             "JOIN Contact_type CONT ON CON.Court_Contact_Type_ID = CONT.Court_Contact_Type_ID " +
             "WHERE C.Court_ID = '3' "+ // I assume the search criteria will be different
             "ORDER BY C.Court_ID"; // Very important: records for the same court must be together

...
string last_id = string.Empty;
while (myDataReader.Read())
{
    string court_id = myDataReader["Court_ID"].ToString();
    string court_name = myDataReader["Court_Name"].ToString();
    string court_town = myDataReader["Town"].ToString();
    string court_pcode = myDataReader["Postcode"].ToString();
    string court_note = myDataReader["Note"].ToString();
    string court_contact_name = myDataReader["Contacts_Name"].ToString();
    string court_contact_desc = myDataReader["Court_Contact_Type_Desc"].ToString();
    string court_contacts_no = myDataReader["Contacts_no"].ToString();
    if (last_id != court_id) {
        // Write court AND contact
        Response.Write("<strong>" + court_name + "</strong><br>" + court_town + "<br>" + court_pcode + "<p>" + court_note + "</p>" + "<p>" + court_contact_name + " - " + court_contact_desc + " : " + court_contacts_no + "</p>");
    } else {
        // Write only contact
        Response.Write("<p>" + court_contact_name + " - " + court_contact_desc + " : " + court_contacts_no + "</p>");
    }
    last_id = court_id;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! That's just the solution I needed and it works a treat. Sorry, its taken a while to implement as the query and code is very much paraphrased from the one I've been working on (to give the essence of the problem without drowning you all in the minute detail). Hopefully I'll be able to work out the other half of the problem (not posted here) now that I know how to work with many to many relationships. If not then I'll be back...
Thanks again @dasblinkenlight! You sir are a gentleman and a scholar.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this (if i got right what you wanted to be shown). Tho i presumed contact and contact type is 1:1 link.

```
SELECT Court_Name, Town, Postcode, Note, contacts
    from Court
    where Court_ID = '3'
    CROSS APPLY
    (
    select substring((
        SELECT ',' + Contact_Name+ ' ' +Contacts_no + ' ' + Court_Contact_Type_Desc 
        FROM Contacts join Contact_Type on  Contacts.Court_Contact_Type_ID = Contact_Type.Court_Contact_Type_ID  
        WHERE Contacts.CourtID = Court.CourtID
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ),2,1000)
        as Contacts    
    ) contacts
```

Tho, this will make you parse data in c# diferently then written in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward method would be to split it into 2 queries.

1st Query: Get the Court with the specified Id.
2nd Query: Get a list of contacts for the Court with the specified Id.

The up side is that it keeps things simple and easy to understand. And, in case there are no contacts found (I don't know how likely that is) you can still output the correct Court address.

The down side is that you fire two SQL queries to your database. That might be a consideration performance wise.

**Beware**: If you make your SQL queries by concatenating strings like in your example... beware of SQL injection attacks! See: [SQL Injection And Parameterized Queries](http://forums.asp.net/t/1568268.aspx)